# Performance bottleneck on SharePoint upload method

Tags: client-object-model, performance, file-upload, file

Trying to eliminate a performance bottleneck on a method doing file and metadata uploads. According to the profiler on a line-by-line of the decompiled code, the majority of time is spent on context.ExecuteQuery(). Below is the code. Any and all suggestions and insights greatly appreciated.

```
Public Shared Sub UploadDocuments(ByVal siteURL As String, _
                                 ByVal credentials As Net.NetworkCredential, _
                                 ByVal documentListName As String, _
                                 ByVal documentListURL As String, _
                                 ByVal sharePointUploads As List(Of SharePointDocumentToSave))

    Using context As New ClientContext(siteURL)
        If Not credentials Is Nothing Then
            context.Credentials = credentials
        End If

        AddHandler context.ExecutingWebRequest, AddressOf ClientContextExecutingWebRequest

        Dim documentsList As List = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentListName)

        For Each documentUpload As SharePointDocumentToSave In sharePointUploads
            Dim fci = New FileCreationInformation()
            With fci
                .Url = siteURL & documentListURL & documentUpload.DocumentName
                .Content = documentUpload.DocumentFile
                .Overwrite = True
            End With

            Dim uploadFile As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File = documentsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci)

            For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In documentUpload.MetaData
                uploadFile.ListItemAllFields(pair.Key) = pair.Value
            Next

            uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update()

            context.ExecuteQuery()
        Next
    End Using

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This is totally normal when working with Client Object Model (CSOM). All operations are batched and not performed until you fire them away using `ExecuteQuery()` or `ExecuteQueryAsync()`. The rest of your code is just setting of local properties, which is converted into an XML format, which is sent to SharePoint at the time you execute the `ExecuteQuery` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In particular, would you have any idea why it might take 20 seconds for a 20KB file to upload? This is being executed over a gigabit network.